# How do I code for this Bridge Bandwidth Problem in python?

Tags: python-3.x

N people are crossing a rickety bridge on a dark night.  The bridge is only strong enough to support 2 people at a time.

It is necessary for the people crossing the bridge to carry a flashlight to guide their way there is only one flashlight and it can only shine a few feet.  The flashlight cannot be thrown (it would break).

Given any number of people with crossing times, compute the paths and combinations of pairs crossing the bridge and what the total time will complete the task.

The program is a simulation that shouldrun for any number of people with varying crossing times. You can randomize the number of people and each crossing times per person.

Below is a CSV file with the names you should use  in your simulation.

Provide the program and flowchart for this assignment.

gNames.csv

Mohamed
Youssef
Ahmed
Mahmoud
Mustafa
Yassin
Khaled
Bilal
Ibrahim
Hassan
Hussein
Karim
Tareq
Ali
Omar
Halim
Santiago
Daniel
Miguel
Liam
Thomas
Augustín
Stevenson
Jayden
Ramón
Luis
Sebastián
Noah
Jackson
Ethan
Joseph
Deven
James
Sheila
Fatma
Maha
Robin
Farida
Aya
Sharon
Ashley
Sahar
Rowan
Hosniya
Hasnaa
Hosna
Gamila
Gamalat
Habiba
Sofía
Alysha
Alice
Emma
Mariana
Widelene
Gabrielle
Ximena
María
Victoria
Sophia
Madison
Olivia
Isabella
Anya
Mary
Florencia
Camila
Léa
Emilia
Valentina
Mirlande
Amelia
Elizabeth
Ava
Chloe
Esther
Arushi
Patricia
Lucía
Julia
Isidora
Islande
Tianna
Beatriz
Mia
Rachel
Linda